# Creating custom widget

Tags: cumulocity

Is it possible (or planned) to create some kind of custom widgets that can be added in dashboards?

For example, I would like to present a list of assets/devices with custom properties (myCustomPropetyA, myCustomPropetyB, ...) as column. I know there is already a Widget "Asset table", and it's pretty good but it's not possible to select custom properties as column. So in this case, and more generally, I think it could be interesting to be able to reference some new widgets, created like AngularJs plugins for example.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly add your own widget implementations to a dashboard. The interface for doing so is http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/core/c8y.ui.service:c8yComponentsProvider.

We will certainly also support custom properties at some point in time.